# $_POST returning empty value

Tags: php, html

**EDIT**: The code seems to work if I place the PHP code in the same file at the HTML. I'll implement this method for now. Thank you for the help!

Whenever I try to echo the values in a PHP file from an input box the values appear to be empty.

Here is my HTML code

```
<form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label><br>
  <input name="person" type="text" /><br>
  <label>Email:</label><br>
  <input name="email" type="email" /><br>
  <label>Opportunity:</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="8"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
</form>
```

This is my sendmail.php file

```
$name = $_POST['person'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message']; 

echo $name;
echo $email;
echo $message;
```

Comment: Did you miss `<?php` tag by chance ?

Comment: can you paste your code exactly?

Comment: check permission of sendmail.php

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran, it will never display blank if he miss `<?php`

Comment: try echo "abcd"; if that too is not coming, then probably some error in your code, you need to check error log

Comment: Pop this at the top of `sendmail.php`, should give you some insight - `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL); echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];`

Comment: the value is empty or blank page?

Comment: @Mark I get "Array ()"

Comment: @Phil It seems to be executing a "GET" instead of a "POST". Can I still use this for sending emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the value in Your current page itself

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['person']))
{
  $name = $_POST['person'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message']; 
  echo "Name".$name;
  echo "Email".$email;
  echo "Message".$message;

 }
?>
 <form action="" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label><br>
  <input name="person" type="text" /><br>
  <label>Email:</label><br>
  <input name="email" type="email" /><br>
  <label>Opportunity:</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="8"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
  </form>
```

or if you want the data in another page

```
 <form action="send.php" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label><br>
  <input name="person" type="text" /><br>
  <label>Email:</label><br>
  <input name="email" type="email" /><br>
  <label>Opportunity:</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="8"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
```

send.php file

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['person']))
{
  $name = $_POST['person'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message']; 
  echo "Name".$name;
  echo "Email".$email;
  echo "Message".$message;

 }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code and it worked fine, so whatever is wrong it is not with the code you have pasted here.

to make sure the post is successful, try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['person']))
echo "passed fine.";
```

Answer (score 0):

check:

```
if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == 'POST'){

   if(isset($_POST['person'])){
      $name = $_POST['person'];
      echo $name;
     }
}
else{
    echo"Your form submission is not correct";
}
```

Comment: Hey I tried using the check and it doesn't seem to be registering as a "POST" method. Any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

HTML

```
  <form action="sendmail.php" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label><br>
  <input name="person" type="text" /><br>
  <label>Email:</label><br>
  <input name="email" type="email" /><br>
  <label>Opportunity:</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="8"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['person'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message']; 

echo $name;
echo $email;
echo $message;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<form action="456.php" method="post">
  <label>Name:</label><br>
  <input name="person" type="text" /><br>
  <label>Email:</label><br>
  <input name="email" type="email" /><br>
  <label>Opportunity:</label><br>
  <textarea name="message" rows="8"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
</form>
<?
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

Comment: create 456.php file
put this code in it. then run on server/wamp/xaamp